# Is it true that $\text {ran} (T^*)$ is closed whenever $\text {ran} (T)$ is closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert space and $T \in \mathcal L (\mathcal H).$ Suppose that $\text {ran} (T)$ is closed. Does it always mean that $\text {ran} (T^*)$ is also closed?

I am trying to prove that by sequential convergence but I couldn't quite do that. Can anybody please help me in this regard? Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is the closed range theorem.

Comment: @daw can you please tell me some references where I can find it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes,  it is.  Let $H_1=\text{Ker}(T)^\perp$ and $H_2=\text{Ran}(T)$.  Also let $\iota _1$ and $\iota _2$ be the inclusions of
$H_1$ and $H_2$ into $H$,  respectively, and observe that $\iota _1^*$ and $\iota _2^*$ are the corresponding projections.

If $T$ has closed range then $\iota _2^*T\iota _1$ is an invertible operator from $H_1$ to $H_2$, whence  its adjoint, namely
$\iota _1^*T^*\iota _2$ is an invertible operator from $H_2$ to $H_1$.

Observing that the range of $T^*$ is contained in $H_1$, we deduce that it is precisely  $H_1$, hence closed.

Comment: If $T$ has closed range then how can we conclude that $\iota_2^* T \iota_1 : H_1 \longrightarrow H_2$ is invertible? Don't we have  $\iota_2^* T \iota_1 = T \iota_1\ $?

Comment: (1) Can you show that the null space of $\iota_2^*T\iota_1$ is $\{0\}$, and that its range is $H_2$?  If so, the conclusion
follows from the open mapping Theorem.  (2) $\iota_2^*T\iota_1$ and $T\iota_1$ coincide on every vector of $H_1$, and
yet they are not the same because their codomains differ.  This makes the former surjective while the later may not be.
The biggest difference, however, is that their adjoints have different domains!!!  People usually don't worry too much about codomains, but when taking adjoints, you can't ignore it!

Comment: Is adjoint of an invertible operator necessarily invertible? Suppose $T : \mathcal H_1 \longrightarrow \mathcal H_2$ is a bounded invertible operator. Then $T$ is surjective and hence $(\text {ker}\ T^*)^{\perp} = \overline {\text {ran}\ T} = \text {ran}\ T = \mathcal H_2.$ In other words $\text {ker}\ T^* = \{0\}.$ So $T^*$ is injective. Also by injectivity of $T$ it follows that $\overline {\text {ran}\ T^*} = \left ( \text {ker}\ T \right )^{\perp} = \{0\}^{\perp} = \mathcal H_1.$ This shows that $\text {ran}\ T^*$ is dense in $\mathcal H_1.$

Comment: From here how can one conclude that $\text {ran}\ T^* = \mathcal H_1\ $?

Comment: If $T$ is invertible, let $S=T^{-1}$.  Then $TS=I_{H_1}$ and $ST=I_{H_2}$, so taking adjoints, $S^*T^*=I_{H_1}$ and $T^ *S^*=I_{H_2}$, hence $T^*$ is invertible.

Comment: Oh! I see. One another question. I don't understand your last paragraph. Can you please be more explicit? Thanks.